# Turn off animated gifs in Gmail

Tags: firefox, gmail

I don't like to be marketed at.  Increasingly, my Gmail emails have increasingly obnoxious gifs playing, marketing at me.

I would like turn off gifs playing, preferably only in Gmail.

If there is a way to turn them off within Gmail's core preferences? If so, that would be great!

If not, is there some AdBlock like rule that can be enabled to block them when using Gmail?  I mostly use Firefox, and an extension or AdBlock rule would be great.

Comment: You can use an email client. Thunderbird, for example, has all that turned off by default. If you're asking about GMail webmail please note it's off-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

**To turn off auto-play animations in Firefox:**

- Type `about:config` in the address bar
- Click "I accept the risk!" if it comes up
- Find "image.animation" using the search box (just type "anim")
- Double-click `image.animation_mode`
- In the next box, type either "once" for the animated GIF to play once, or `none`
  so they never can

The downside here is you can't ever get the file to play later without reverting the settings.

**SuperStop extension**

For a more flexible software solution, install the
[SuperStop extension for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/superstop/):

> SuperStop adds a Shift+Esc shortcut and toolbar button that stops background requests and animations even when the Firefox Stop button is disabled.

Comment: this is helpful - thank you for looking into this. I would say, stopping all gifs, in a setting deeply buried in firefox is tough. vs., a way to do it only for a domain (e.g. gmail) . That said, it's kind of an answer, albeit not preferred one;        ..............

SuperStop is also tough - it stops all kinds of things well beyond gifs, and takes user action. Which means I've already been manipulated into noticing and engaging with their marketing. ... ......I'll mark the answer as useful, though perhaps not a full answer, and keep looking.

Comment: How often do you really _want_ to re-play a GIF?  It's rare for me; in which case, I expect I can just download the file and re-play it locally.  Firefox setting is a useful solution for me, thanks.